# The tensorflow tutorial cannot load keras library

Tags: tensorflow

I'm completely new to Tensorflow, and I've tried installing it on a Windows 10 desktop.

I've followed the instructions on the Tensorflow web site.

Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.16299 Build 16299
python x64 3.6.7
pip 18.1

I've set up a virtual environment and it has these packages.

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
absl-py             0.6.1
astor               0.7.1
gast                0.2.0
grpcio              1.16.0
h5py                2.8.0
Keras-Applications  1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.5
Markdown            3.0.1
numpy               1.15.4
pip                 18.1
protobuf            3.6.1
setuptools          40.5.0
six                 1.11.0
tensorboard         1.12.0
tensorflow          1.12.0
termcolor           1.1.0
virtualenv          16.1.0
Werkzeug            0.14.1
wheel               0.32.2
```

If I run the verify install :

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

then it responds with :

```
2018-11-12 14:22:54.667533: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
tf.Tensor(-344.4322, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

However if I try to run the example script in the tutorials (the one you see on the page that uses the mnist dataset) then I get the error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
```

However if I run the following the tutorial script line by line via the python prompt then it executes without exception.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Keras was added to tensorflow in version `1.4`.
Contrary to the package list you pasted above, the error message suggests to me you're probably running an older version of Tensorflow when you run the example script.

You can verify that by adding

`print(tf.VERSION)`

to your script and running it and if the Tensorflow version is older than `1.4` you will just need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

omg.  school boy error.

when trying the tutorial code, I created a python script called tensorflow.py

hence there was a namespace/class-name clash.

i renamed the script to bob.py and hey presto all works.